# Mount a volume in AWS copilot task run

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm using copilot to execute containers that test our code.
Actually I can make the tests run with the following command:

```
copilot task run -n <app_name> --default \
    --image <image_from_ecr> \
    --command <test_file> --cpu 1024 --memory 2048
```

This creates the service based on the app image and executes the <test_file>. If I use the `--follow` tag I can see the execution and all goes well.

What I need now, is to be able to read the test outputs that nightwatch writes inside the container.
I used to mount a volume when I was executing the tests with docker run.

But now I don't know how to mount a volume with the `copilot task run` command.

And if there is another way to get the files generated any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sergi, you can't currently mount volumes in Copilot tasks, but you can use the `--task-role` flag to specify a particular IAM role that the container can use to make AWS CLI or API calls (for example, upload your nightwatch data to an S3 bucket. The AWS Docs have some [helpful tips](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#create_task_iam_policy_and_role). Once you create a bucket and IAM role and specify the role in `task run --task-role $myRoleArn`, you can call `aws s3 cp` from inside your task to upload your data to S3 for further analysis

Comment: So sorry you waited so long for an answer here. We don't have a ton of visibility into Stack Overflow, so in the future you might get more activity on your questions by cutting an issue to our [Github repository](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues). Thanks so much for giving Copilot a try!

Comment: Thanks @AustinEly, that was exactly what I did the day after answering the question. Used S3 to copy info to and from the containers run with copilot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to mount a volume to a task executed this way.

The solution for my case is:

1. Execute the task with an IAM role capable of writing to a S3 bucket.
2. Upload the output testing data to the bucket after the tests are finished. This is done from the task itself.
3. Download the tests outputs from the S3 bucket from the script that controls the test executions in the host.
   This is the script that runs tasks using copilot, so knows all parameters and options and can download the appropiate folder from the bucket.